# If else evaluation

Tags: c++, if-statement

Suppose I have the following statement:

```
    bool foo=true;
    if (foo){
            foo=false;
    }
    else{
             //do stuff
    }
```

Will it enter the **else** condition, or is the **if** evaluated once discarding  the **else** immediately?

Comment: it's a fork in a one-way road. the condition is evaluated, then you drive down the appropriate fork. changing the condition AFTER you've gone down the fork doesn't magically rewind time and make you suddenly take the other fork.

Comment: Yes, once if is evaluated the else will not be checked. Of course for safety you can put an break; statement at the end of if block;

Comment: @Imran: For *safety*? That's totally insane. An if statement isn't a loop, you cannot break from it, and even if that made any sense at all, it would be horrendous. You should *understand* the basic idioms of the language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`else` won't evaluate because the condition's executed only once.

When you say `foo=true` `foo` is checked, then the code in *one of the conditions* is executed. If `foo` is `true`, then `foo=false` is done and execution stops.

Answer (score 2):

`if` is a split. Depending on the value of the expression, either the "if" or the "else" part of the code is evaluated, but not both, and that's all about it.

In your example, because the value of `foo` is `true`, the "if" branch runs (setting `foo` to `false`) and the "else" branch is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement does not provide a way to fall through to the `else` part if the condition evaluates to `true`.

If you need such a feature, you can use `switch`:

```
bool foo = true;
switch (foo) {
case true:
    foo = false;
    // FALL THROUGH
default:
    //...
}
```